# Deduce template-argument from std::function's return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

I usually never write C++ and today I tried experimented with C++ templates. I implemented a Maybe type which looks like this

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template<typename T>
class TMaybe
{
  T value;
public:
  TMaybe() : value(nullptr){}
  TMaybe(T &&v) : value(v){}
  TMaybe(T v) : value(v){}
};

template<typename T, typename R>
TMaybe<R> maybe_if(const TMaybe<T> &m, std::function<R(T v)> f){
  return (m.value != nullptr) ? TMaybe<R>(f(m)) : TMaybe();
}

int main(){
  int i = 10;
  auto m = TMaybe<int>(i);
  auto plus_ten = [](int i) -> int {return i + 10;};
  maybe_if(m, plus_ten); // could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<R(T)>' from 'main::<lambda_17413d9c06b6239cbc7c7dd22adf29dd>'
}
```

but the error message `could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<R(T)>' from 'main::<lambda_17413d9c06b6239cbc7c7dd22adf29dd>'` is not very helpful. Can you spot the error?

Comment: That's not what `std::function` is for. Make that argument type a template argument instead.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Could you show me the syntax for this?

Comment: You have a compilation error even before the marked line. Are you using the Microsoft compiler? More importantly, your design is broken. C++ is not Java. You cannot shove a `nullptr` into any random type. Try to instantiate `TMaybe<std::string>` or just about anything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler can only deduce `R` from `f` if you pass it an actual instance of `std::function<R(T)>`; passing a lambda won't work, as a lambda isn't an instance of a `std::function` specialization.

The correct way to write your code is to allow any functor type, and deduce `R` from it:

```
template<typename T, typename F, typename R = typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type>
TMaybe<R> maybe_if(const TMaybe<T> &m, F f){
  return (m.value != nullptr) ? TMaybe<R>(f(m.value)) : TMaybe();
}
```

Comment: When I replace the original source with your template (g++-4.8), it still reports a lot of errors.

Comment: @OlafDietsche well sure, there's lots of other issues with the code; but I'm sure OP can address them themselves.

Comment: "I usually never write C++ and today I tried experimented with C++ templates.", I hope so.

Answer (score 1):

[Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) happens before implicit conversion of Lambda to `std::fucntion`.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

Hence compiler can **only** deduce "`R`" (return-type) from "`f`" (functor) if you pass an actual instance of `std::function<R(T)>` type.

## Example for C++20 <sup>(and maybe later)</sup>

Use `std::type_identity_t`, like:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// ...

template<typename T, typename R>
TMaybe<R> maybe_if(const TMaybe<T> &m, std::function< std::type_identity_t<R> (T v)> f)
{
  return (m.value != nullptr) ? TMaybe<R>(f(m)) : TMaybe();
}
```

## Example for older compilers

If C++20 is not allowed for your project, you need to take the functor-type as template-argument, and deduce `R` from that.

#### For MSVC 2015 use `std::result_of`

```cpp
template<typename T, typename F, typename R = typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type>
TMaybe<R> maybe_if(const TMaybe<T> &m, F f)
{
  return (m.value != nullptr) ? TMaybe<R>(f(m.value)) : TMaybe();
}
```

#### For MSVC 2010 use `decltype`

MSVC 2010 has `std::result_of`, but does not allow default template argument for functions,
hence we do something like:

```cpp
#define MY_RESULT_OF(functor, argType) decltype( functor(*static_cast<argType * >(nullptr)) )

template<typename T, typename F>
auto maybe_if(const TMaybe<T> &m, F f) -> TMaybe< MY_RESULT_OF(f, T) >
{
  typedef MY_RESULT_OF(f, T) R;
  return (m.value != nullptr) ? TMaybe<R>(f(m.value)) : TMaybe();
}
```