# Could not deduce template argument (vector, std::function)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I created a templated function of which I am trying to automatically deduce the template argument.
MCVE([compile it](https://godbolt.org/z/SPG7eT)):

```
template<class Value, class Allocator>
void foo(const std::vector<Value, Allocator>& v, const std::function<void(const Value&)>& f)
{
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    foo<int>(v, [](const int&){}); //okay
    //foo(v, [](const int&){}); //not okay
    return 0;
}
```

I first thought the Allocator could not be deduced but that does not seem to solve it.
My next guess is it has something to do with the lambda to std::function but no idea on further steps there. Anybody got any clues about what I need to do to make this deducible?

Ps: I know "const int&" could become "int" but in the real code there is a non scalar data type there.

Comment: You might get rid of `std::function` and have `template<class Value, class Allocator, typename Func>
void foo(const std::vector<Value, Allocator>& v, Func&& f)
{
}`

Comment: Please note that `std::vector` might have more than 2 template arguments and your code fails to take that into account.

Comment: @rubenvb what do you mean, looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector I only see implementations with 2 template arguments.

Comment: @Jarod42 good suggestion but I also quite like it that the signature shows what arguments should be passed to the function/lambda.

Comment: C++20 should probably have concept for that :-)

Comment: @turoni That's the specification. If an implementation wants to pull some optimization tricks or extend functionality, it may well add extra template arguments and be conformant nonetheless.

Comment: **See also [Deduce template-argument from std::function's return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23828930/8740349)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) happens before implicit conversion of Lambda to `std::fucntion`.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

Meaning type deduction of the template parameter `Value` on the 2nd function argument `f` fails because the implicit conversion from lambda to `std::function` are not considered.

As you showed you can specify template arguments explicitly (to bypass the template argument deduction). Or you can exclude the 2nd argument from deduction by using [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) to declare it as [non deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

> The *nested-name-specifier* (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator `::`) of a type that was specified using a [qualified-id](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers):

e.g.

```
template<class Value, class Allocator>
void foo(const std::vector<Value, Allocator>& v, const std::function<void(const std::type_identity_t<Value>&)>& f)
{
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gxAtKqKbUoKaGSOO)

PS: [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is supported from C++20; if the compiler you're using doesn't support it it's not hard to make one.

Comment: Gonna take a while to understand why this works but hopefully https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts helps. Thanks.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that std::type_identity<Value>::Type is what makes the 2nd Value argument to the left of the scope resolution operator :: and thus non deduced context?

Comment: @turoni Yes. Then `Value` would be only deduced on the 1st function argument and anything is fine.

Comment: This took me on a deeper template deduction context rabid hole than I expected but thank you for helping me understand.

Comment: `std::type_identity` is excellent in its simplicity. I must have written tons of complicated solutions that could have been simplified using a helper like that. Note to self: Now, _remember_ this one.

Comment: @turoni You're defining `type` in `type_identity` as `private`; make it `public`. :) https://godbolt.org/z/7_DXBt